# Excel If Statement Referencing another Sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, spreadsheet

I have Sheet1 named "Suppliers" and Sheet2 is named "Online Order". Suppliers has a list of suppliers we use at work and some of them have to be ordered online. Sheet 2 is meant to have the login info to make the order. Suppliers has ColumnD say Yes or No if it's an online order while ColumnA is the list of suppliers.

I want Online Order to only have those supplier names on it. Basically, IF Suppliers ColumnD says Yes, Online Order ColumnA is filled with Supplier ColumnA of only the lines that have a Yes in ColumnD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kezbL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeze2.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sounds like a job for advanced filter. You can use an if statement but you will end up with blanks for the suppliers that are marked with 'No`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have linked the images. first is what i want to put in, second is what i want it to do

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the 1st listed item in "Online Order" to be located at A2. Put this in A2, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, then drag downwards :

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Suppliers!$C:$C,SMALL(IF(Suppliers!$D:$D="Yes",ROW(Suppliers!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW(Suppliers!$C:$C))+1),ROWS($A$2:A2))),"")`

My references : [TheGoodReference](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-rows) and [ExampleForOtherScenario](https://superuser.com/questions/1274325/attempting-to-transpose-two-column-table-in-excel-using-first-column-to-group-va/1349909#1349909)

Hope it helps.. ( :